# Can see my HDD in Windows, but not from Linux live boot

Tags: dual-boot, hard-disk, live-usb

I've just gotten a new laptop (Acer Aspire A315-56), where I can't see my HDD from a Linux live boot. When I'm opening GParted, it's only showing one disk and it's the USB Drive from where I've live booted it. My laptop came preinstalled with Windows 10 Home.

I've looked up Ask Ubuntu and similar forums, and according to the suggestions, I've tried out the following:

```
Set the SATA Mode to "AHCI" from "Optane without RAID"

Disabled Fast Boot from BIOS

Disabled Secure Boot

Disabled Fast Startup and Hibernate from Windows 10 Power Options
```

Unfortunately, none of those turned out to work for me.

As I'm not able to see the HDD from Linux, I'm not able to install it. Can anyone help me out with making the HDD visible from Linux? Using a Virtual Machine isn't really a solution.

Also, I've checked that upon hitting `sudo lshw` in the terminal, the SATA Controller shows up there. So, the SATA controller's driver is in the kernel.

I'm live booting Ubuntu, if that helps.

Comment: what does `lsblk` show you?

Comment: It's probably not a HDD but a SSD. And that means it could be a NVMe SSD, which has nothing to do with SATA at all; a NVMe SSD is essentially a PCIe device, so check `lspci`. In Linux, NVMe drives have a different device name scheme: `/dev/nvmeXnYpZ`, where X is the number of the NVMe drive, Y is the number of a *storage namespace* within it (in consumer-grade device, probably always 1), and Z is the number of the partition. The driver for NVMe devices is a kernel module named `nvme`.

Comment: Many have also had to update UEFI and update SSD firmware. Acer Begins Publishing UEFI Firmware Updates For Linux Users On LVFS For Fwupd,  Aspire A315 laptop first
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Acer-Updates-On-LVFS
Acer Aspire A315-53-386P remove RAID from drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa I would expect 20.04.1 to work better than 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118751/has-anyone-successfully-dual-booted-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-their-acer-predator-heli

Comment: @BitFreak this is what `lsblk` gives: https://pastebin.com/Cbs2ppWt

Comment: @telcoM It's an HDD for sure. You can check the specs for the given model. Here's what `lspci` gives: https://pastebin.com/S9NaRSYt

Comment: @oldfred in all of those links, the HDD is atleast visible somewhere from Linux in their case. In my case, the Linux live boot is almost pretending as if there's no HDD in my laptop at all. `sudo lshw` and `lspci` just mention the Intel SATA Controller, and that's it.

Comment: So it's an Intel Ice Lake-LP SATA controller. The support for it was added to the kernel.org mainline in July 2018 [(commit)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/ata/ahci.c?id=ba44579141f9e2c0229e6e7eeb00b5fa68f0f74a), so Ubuntu 18.04 would be too old for it unless using an updated kernel. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to use?

Comment: @telcoM I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, here's what `lsb_release -a` gives me: https://pastebin.com/aqXLmy1D

Comment: If you did an UEFI update, it may have reset some of the parameters you changed. Double check those. Windows updates may run an UEFI update and Windows updates often turn fast start up back on. And just booting Windows may run an update.

Comment: @oldfred I just checked, the parameters haven't changed even after the Windows Update and about the UEFI update, I haven't yet gotten any. By parameters you mean the SATA Mode: AHCI, Secure Boot: Off, etc right?

Comment: Yes, I have to keep a list and use that to change UEFI settings after every UEFI  update with my system. Some have other settings to enable/disable a drive. Or if NVMe drive is plugged in, some SATA port becomes unavailable or vice versa.

Comment: @oldfred but my HDD is definitely 'enabled', because otherwise how is it visible from Windows? For some reason, only a Linux system appears to ignore the presence of an HDD in my system.

In my BIOS/UEFI settings, it shows: `HDD0: [Enabled], HDD1: [Enabled]`

Comment: Did you see this question. He had to remove RAID data from drive to get it to work. Acer Aspire A315-53-386P remove RAID from drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa

Comment: @oldfred In that answer he's `dmraid`ing a disk that's visible in `/dev`. In my system, only a `/dev/sda` is visible where this `sda` is nothing but the USB drive I'm live-booting Linux from. The hard disk just doesn't show up in `/dev`. My `lsblk`, `lspci` and `lshw` outputs are there in my previous comments on this question. You can go through them for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really a solution more of a workaround, put the laptop to sleep and wake it backup and the SATA drive will appear.

If your kernel has the debugging enabled for power management you add test_suspend=mem and suspend.pm_test_delay=2 to the boot time options.
unfortunately most kernels are released without them compiled in.

The main thing is after getting the OS installed, you have to wait for the kernel to start booting shut the lid or use the keyboard shortcut to put it to sleep wait a second wake it up and let the computer finish booting, or compile a custom kernel and enable the power management debugging and suspend test options in the config.